# Why does this input fields conflict with each other?

Tags: visualforce-component, inputfield

I have two components that are conflicting with each other:

component1:

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="cntact" description="A Contact for the component." type="Contact" required="true"/>

    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.New_Contact_Component}" var="f">

        <apex:outputLabel value="{!f.label}: "/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!cntact[f]}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

component2:

```
<apex:component controller="NewSObjects_Ctrl">
<apex:attribute name="lotsComp" description="A list of Lots for the component." type="Lot__c[]" required="false" assignTo="{!lots}"/>
    <apex:dataTable value="{!lots}" var="lot" id="lotsTable">
        <apex:repeat var="f1" value="{!$ObjectType.Lot__c.FieldSets.New_Component}">
            <apex:column headerValue="{!f1.label}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!lot[f1]}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:dataTable>
    <apex:commandLink action="{!addLot}" value="{!$Label.Add} {!$Label.New}" reRender="lotsTable"/>
    <apex:commandLink action="{!removeLot}" value="{!$Label.Remove} {!$Label.Last}" reRender="lotsTable"/>
</apex:component>
```

NewSObjects_Ctrl class:

```
public with sharing class NewSObjects_Ctrl {
    public List<Lot__c> lots {get;set;}

    public PageReference addLot(){
        lots.add(new Lot__c());
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference removeLot(){
        if (lots.size() > 0)
            lots.remove(lots.size() - 1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController=“Custom__c” extensions=“someExt” action=“{!someAction}”>
    <apex:form>
        <c:NewContact cntact="{!cntact}"/>
        <c:NewLotsTable lotsComp="{!lots}"/>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Save}" action="{!save1}”/>
</apex:page>
```

Each component works great by itself when used in a VF page, the problem is when I have both components in the same VF page, the second one stops working (Add and Remove doesn't work).

Any ideas why this could be happening?